Ubuntu Apt packages failing with 403
I have a new Ubuntu 24.04 install and am trying to do a sudo apt-get update.
I'm getting the following error:
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]

A couple weird things here:

This file doesn't actually exist. If you go to that URL in a browser, you'll get a 404. Looking at the listing of the parent directory, there's a Components-amd64.yml.gz file, but no Components-amd64.yml file.
The file doesn't exist and I get a 404 in the browser, but I get a 403 through apt-get? Why?

So my questions are, why is it looking for a file that doesn't exist, and why is it getting a 403 instead of a 404?
I also tried
sudo apt-get -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz update

To try to get it to find the .gz file, but it had no effect (same error).
Full command output:
:~$ sudo apt update

Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease [126 kB]

Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease [126 kB]

Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease

Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease [256 kB]

Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/main amd64 Packages [377 kB]

Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/main Translation-en [81.6 kB]

Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 Packages [530 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [128 kB]

Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe amd64 Packages [374 kB]

Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe amd64 Components

Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse amd64 Components

Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe amd64 Components

Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse amd64 Components

Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe amd64 Components

Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse amd64 Components

Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe amd64 Components

Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse amd64 Components

Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe amd64 Components

Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse amd64 Components

Err:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe amd64 Components

  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.82 80]

Err:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse amd64 Components

  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.82 80]

Fetched 1999 kB in 3s (611 kB/s)

Reading package lists... Done

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-updates/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.82 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.82 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.


Please edit your question to show complete output of sudo apt update. There may be vital clues elsewhere in that output.

I've updated it to include the full output.

There's a possible clue: Your GET numbering jumps from 8 to 35, and GET 8 repeats 27 times. Then 36 and 37 repeat five times before erroring out. Is this your actual terminal output? Did GET 8 really repeat 27 times on your screen?

It's different each time I run it, but yes, it repeats a lot of them. I just ran it again and it repeated Get:18 about 15 times.
